# How do I add a number to avariable every set line of code?

Tags: python, variables, automation, numbers, pyautogui

I have a line of code with a number. The code is copypasted multiple times so it can run many times. The problem is the numbers don't change. I am using pyautogui so the following is an example.

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.typewrite("Hello")

pyautogui.scroll(1)

pyautogui.typewrite("Hello")

pyautogui.scroll(1)

pyautogui.typewrite("Hello")

pyautogui.scroll(1)
```

On the second and 3rd pastes of the code, how can I have them automatically be 2, 3 etc?

Comment: Hey Jaiden, have you tried a for loop?

`for i in range(2):
    pyautogui.typewrite("Hello")
    pyautogui.scroll(i)`

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop.

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    pyautogui.typewrite("Hello")
    pyautogui.scroll(i)
```